# Prove that $f(x,y)=xy$ is differentiable using the definition

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, inequality

Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=xy$. Prove $f$ is differentiable.

According to the definition I have to show this $$\frac{\|f((x_0,y_0)+(h_1,h_2)) - f(x_0,y_0)-T(h_1\space  h_2)\|}{\|(h_1,h_2)\|}\to 0$$

But I got stuck in the proof.

\begin{align}
& \frac{\|f((x_0,y_0)+(h_1,h_2))-f(x_0,y_0)-T(h_1\space  h_2)\|}{\|(h_1,h_2\|} \\[10pt]
= {} & \frac{\|(x_0+h_1)(y_0+h_2)-x_0y_0-(x,y)(h_1\space  h_2)\|}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}} \\[10pt]
\le {} &\frac{\|x_0h_2+y_0h_1+h_1h_2\|}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}+\frac{\|-(x,y)(h_1\space h_2)\|}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}
\end{align}
and I think I the first term after the inequality goes to zero, but what happen to the second term?

How can it goes to zero too?

Comment: You have not said what the hypotheses are. What you wrote, with linear mapping $T,$ is the definition of (Frechet) differentiability.

Comment: @WillJagy Hypothesis? The exercise just says: Let $f:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x,y)=xy$. Prove $f$ is differentiable.

Comment: In that case, repeat that part in the question body.

Comment: The linear map your looking for is $T(h_1,h_2)=(y_0,x_0)(h_1,h_2)$, not $T(h_1,h_2)=(x,y)(h_1,h_2)$ as you have written

Comment: @Aweygan and therefore everything goes to zero, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  $T (h_1 ,h_2) =  \nabla f (x_0 , y_0)^T (h_1,h_2) = y_0 h_1 + x_0 h_2 $

Therefore

$$\frac{|f((x_0,y_0)+(h_1,h_2)) - f(x_0,y_0)-T(h_1\space  h_2)|}{\|(h_1,h_2)\|}= \frac{  | h_1h_2 | }{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}    \leq  |h_2|  $$

Comment: and then as $(h_1,h_2)\to 0$, $\frac{\|f((x_0,y_0)+(h_1,h_2)) - f(x_0,y_0)-T(h_1\space  h_2)\|}{\|(h_1,h_2)\|}\to 0$, right?

Comment: @AnneliseToft Right ,   since $$\frac{  | h_1h_2 | }{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}    \leq  |h_2|  $$

Comment: where does that came from? I  don't see it

Comment: @AnneliseToft     Do you agree  that

$$\frac{  | h_1 | }{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}    \leq  1$$

?

Comment: yes but I don't see why the inequality holds, this $\frac{  | h_1h_2 | }{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}    \leq  |h_2|$

Comment: Multiply both sides by $|h_2|$ .

Is it clear Now?   @AnneliseToft

Comment: I said yes, but I though it was an implication of $\frac{  | h_1h_2 | }{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}    \leq  |h_2|$ so..

Comment: $$  |h_1|^2  \leq   h^2_1   +  h^2_2    $$

then    $$  |h_1|  \leq  \sqrt{ h^2_1   +  h^2_2 }   $$ 

So $$\frac{  | h_1 | }{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}    \leq  1$$

@AnneliseToft

Comment: Now it's clear :D thanks!